# Extract public key from private key in pem format

Tags: objective-c, macos, openssl

How can I implement the effect of following command in Objective-C?

```
openssl rsa -in mykey.pem -pubout > mykey.pub
```

I'm able to generate a private key in pem format.

Here is the code I use to read the private key into a openssl RSA object.

```objc
BIO* bpPrivate = nil;
NSString *filePath = .....
const char *path = [filePath UTF8String];
bpPrivate = BIO_new_file(path, "r");
_rsa = PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey(bpPrivate, NULL, 0, NULL);
```

I want to extract the public key from the private key.

Comment: Objective-C consumes regular C, so its OK to use anything written against C. You don't have to restrict yourself to Objective-C classes. In fact, you are not limiting yourself by calling OpenSSL's `PEM_read_bio_RSAPrivateKey`.

Answer (score 0):

In memory, there is no notion of ASN.1, DER, PEM or other encodings. A RSA key uses the same structure for both the public and private key. For a public key, some fields are not used. If you are interested in the fields, then visit [PKCS #1](http://www.emc.com/emc-plus/rsa-labs/standards-initiatives/pkcs-rsa-cryptography-standard.htm) or [RFC 3447](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3447.txt).

So, given an `RSA*`, all you need to do is call `PEM_write_bio_RSAPublicKey` (even with a private key). You can also use `PEM_write_RSAPublicKey` (even with a private key). See [`pem(3)`](http://www.openssl.org/docs/crypto/pem.html) for all the read and write functions.

You can also accomplish it the long way by way of `RSAPublicKey_dup`. It will take a priavte key (i.e., a `RSA*`) and return a public key (i.e., a `RSA*`). But its kind of an unnecessary step for the most part. It might be useful to keep the key in memory, if you have that requirement.

```c
RSA* privKey = NULL;
RSA* pubKey = NULL;
BIGNUM* exp = NULL;

privKey = RSA_new();
ASSERT(privKey != NULL);

exp = BN_new();
ASSERT(exp != NULL);

rc = BN_set_word(exp, RSA_F4);
ASSERT(rc == 1);

rc = RSA_generate_key_ex(privKey, 1024, exp, NULL);
ASSERT(rc == 1);

pubKey = RSAPublicKey_dup(privKey);
ASSERT(pubKey != NULL);

RSA_print_fp(stdout, pubKey, 0);

if(pubKey) {
    RSA_free(pubKey);
}

if(privKey) {
    RSA_free(privKey);
}

if(exp) {
    BN_free(exp);
}
```

The `RSA_print_fp` results in:

```bash
$ ./t.exe
Public-Key: (1024 bit)
Modulus:
    00:c3:30:67:d9:11:59:9b:85:7a:1a:95:fa:fd:c0:
    dd:cd:21:d6:41:6b:16:70:c2:57:9a:f2:d2:bd:3b:
    c0:02:7b:6a:ab:7f:13:a7:53:2f:31:10:08:3a:62:
    28:40:5f:82:19:23:f6:0f:78:f5:e3:e4:19:a1:b4:
    73:65:35:10:db:17:28:41:42:ba:df:8c:18:3b:d8:
    62:52:65:61:0e:cd:60:28:c9:75:a8:5b:46:a4:89:
    db:78:89:49:87:5d:7f:ce:d0:44:c4:fd:4a:74:66:
    d4:46:21:c1:89:97:28:de:43:e9:94:50:f1:36:85:
    a7:ef:6c:6d:6f:5d:78:00:67
Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
```

You can add a call to `PEM_write_RSAPublicKey`:

```c
FILE* file = fopen("rsa-pub.pem", "w");
ASSERT(file != NULL);

rc = PEM_write_RSAPublicKey(file, pubKey);
```

Then:

```bash
$ ./t.exe
$ cat rsa-pub.pem 
-----BEGIN RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGJAoGBAMb2jIVcTttHRqG9szv3CFZ742l7LxnVoM6oOfQXNOwabh+GB4Srf4IA
XRcGan7cj1DShnoPw9fp3IeuAUerk3xz8yPXCw09dLwrFcsmItLVnSLoRtpHnxN5
30Wd5vKpvKTLIQnurGo05s911ukFJeGo2y2OjSnTiQcJLUdt497tAgMBAAE=
-----END RSA PUBLIC KEY-----
```

Comment: Thanks jww, it is working as I expect. RSAPublicKey_dup solve my problem.

Comment: @yohon Can we create PEM certificate with Eliptice Curve "ecdsa-with-SHA256" 
"http://oid-info.com/cgi-bin/display?oid=1.2.840.10045.4.3.2&action=display" ?

Comment: @oid-info.com/cgi-bin - See [Elliptic Curve Cryptography](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Elliptic_Curve_Cryptography) on the OpenSSL wiki.